# Subseting object with reactive values will fail

Tags: r, shiny

1. List item

I have a problem with reactive values not working as i think it should work.

The small code below describes the problem. The function firstsub2 will basically subset an object into a smaller one by removing samples we don´t want to keep for some reason (this is using the subset_samples function from the phyloseq biocondcutor package).

UI.R

```
 myui <-     
  fluidPage(


            navbarPage("Project",



                       ## foldchanges
                       tabPanel("Foldchanges",
                                titlePanel("Permanova: Analysis of variance using distance matrices"),


                                # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
                                sidebarLayout(

                                  # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
                                  sidebarPanel(

                                    actionButton("dofoldchanges", "Generate foldchanges")

                                       ),


                                  mainPanel(
                                    # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
                                    tabsetPanel(id="foldchanges",type = "tabs",
                                                tabPanel(title="Summary", value=1, verbatimTextOutput("summary_foldchanges"))
                                                #tabPanel("Table pairwise",value=4, dataTableOutput("tablepermanovapw"))


                                    )

                                  )
                                )
                       )

                      )
               )
```

SERVER.R

```
#To install phyloseq
#source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
#biocLite("phyloseq")

library(shiny)
library(phyloseq)

myserver <- function(input, output, session) {

source("foldchanges.R", local = TRUE)
}
```

foldchanges.R

```
# Filter object
firstsub2 <- reactive({
  values$rn <- as.character(sample_data(values$physeq)[,"Description"]$Description)))
  cat(values$rn)

  #The subset_samples function below will not work
  filteredtaxo <- subset_samples(values$physeq, Description %in% values$rn)  
  return(filteredtaxo)

})


values <- reactiveValues()
observeEvent(input$dofoldchanges, {

  rich_sparse_biom = system.file("extdata", "rich_sparse_otu_table.biom", package = "phyloseq")
  physeq = import_biom(rich_sparse_biom, parseFunction = parse_taxonomy_greengenes)
  print(physeq)
  values$physeq <- physeq

  values$filtered <- firstsub2()


})
```

This example will basically return the same object that was imported

Comment: Your code/error is not reproducible. 1) Its not a complete shiny-App and 2) Input-Data is missing.

Comment: @SeGa Hi, I have added a fully reproducible example.

Comment: i think the problem comes from the subset_samples function of the packages ``#'  # subset_samples(GlobalPatterns, SampleType=="Ocean")
subset_samples <- function(physeq, ...){
 if( is.null(sample_data(physeq)) ){ 
  cat("Nothing subset. No sample_data in physeq.\n")
  return(physeq)
 } else {
  oldDF <- as(sample_data(physeq), "data.frame")
  newDF <- subset(oldDF, ...)
  if( class(physeq) == "sample_data" ){
   return(sample_data(newDF))
  } else {
   sample_data(physeq) <- sample_data(newDF)
   return(physeq)
  }
 }
}``

Answer (score 0):

Your code still has some errors, especially the server file (Some unnecessary commas).

I think your app works as it should, but it will always be the same file as the `values$rn` will always be the same. I included another line (uncommented right now) below your `subset_sample`, to test if the subsetting is working. If you change `values$rn` to `"human skin"` for example, you will see different results.

But I didn't figure out how to change it. When taking only the first element of `values$rn` for example, I'm getting an **object not found** error. But when I include "human skin" like that, it works.

But maybe that helps you already.

```
library(shiny)
# source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
# biocLite("phyloseq")
library(phyloseq)

myui <- {fluidPage(
    navbarPage("Project",
               ## foldchanges
               tabPanel("Foldchanges",
                        titlePanel("Permanova: Analysis of variance using distance matrices"),
                        # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
                        sidebarLayout(
                          # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
                          sidebarPanel(
                            actionButton("dofoldchanges", "Generate foldchanges")
                          ),
                          mainPanel(
                            # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
                            tabsetPanel(id="foldchanges",type = "tabs",
                                        tabPanel(title="Summary", value=1, 
                                                 verbatimTextOutput("summary_foldchanges"),
                                                 verbatimTextOutput("summary_physeq"))
                                        )))))
)}

myserver <- function(input, output, session) {

  values <- reactiveValues()

  firstsub2 <- reactive({
    req(values$physeq)
    input$dofoldchanges

    values$rn <- as.character(sample_data(values$physeq)[,"Description"]$Description)
    cat(values$rn)


    #The subset_samples function below will not work
    filteredtaxo <- subset_samples(values$physeq, "Description" %in% values$rn)
    ## Change it to one of the next lines, to see that subsetting works.
    # filteredtaxo <- subset_samples(values$physeq, Description %in% "human skin")
    # filteredtaxo <- subset_samples(values$physeq, Description %in% "human gut")

    return(filteredtaxo)
  })


  observeEvent(input$dofoldchanges, {
    rich_sparse_biom = system.file("extdata", "rich_sparse_otu_table.biom", package = "phyloseq")
    physeq = import_biom(rich_sparse_biom, parseFunction = parse_taxonomy_greengenes)
    print(physeq)
    values$physeq <- physeq

    values$filtered <- firstsub2()
  })

  output$summary_physeq <- renderPrint({
    req(values$physeq)
    values$physeq
  })  
  output$summary_foldchanges <- renderPrint({
    req(values$filtered)
    values$filtered
  })
}

shinyApp(myui, myserver)
```